# getJSON get newest result/post from category

Tags: jquery, json

I have this code to pull the newest post from a category. There must a be simple way to display.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = 'MY URL';
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
      for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
      {
       if(data.items[i] != null)
      {
         var current = data.items[i];
         var post =  '<li><a href="http://MYSITE.com/' + current.ITSLINK + '"><img src= "'+current.ASSETSURL+'" alt ="'+current.ITSFILENAME+'"></a></li>' ;
           $('DIVE NAME').append(post);
        }
     }
  });
});
```

This pulls the newest post from the cateogey and places it into a list/slider

Is their a way to simply it so it will not be inside a loop but just one single post on its own.

Comment: That `for` loop is useless. It executes once (with `0` as `i`'s value) and that's it.

Comment: arrghhhh how do/can i make it so it can be executed as many times?

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/BDX7H/ ? Is this what you're asking?

Comment: I think you may have solved my problem. Bit of a n00b question that was. But i basically want to add the latest post into a slider, so when a new post is created I can add a category to it and will go straight into a slider.

Comment: i had problems with this with opera and old IE, as you say the FOR loop is useless.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure I follow. The `for` was useless because all it ever did was to loop only once, always (we usually apply a `for` when needing to run several times the same commands). What I did was to remove the `for`, but the behavior of both versions should be the exact same. Is this what you needed? Just the same behavior, but in less lines of code (and without the `for`)?

Comment: hang on then this was the original topic i started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645611/json-flexslider-not-loading-iamges-in-some-browsers. I have the flexslider that goes through 6 categories and pulls the latest from each category and chucks the old er ones out. But for some reason it doesnt load on when the page loads. it explains it a bit in the the link i put on here.

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'MY URL';
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {   
        $.each(data.items, function(idx, item){
            var current = item;
            var post =  '<li><a href="http://MYSITE.com/' + current.ITSLINK + '"><img src= "'+current.ASSETSURL+'" alt ="'+current.ITSFILENAME+'"></a></li>' ;
            $('DIVE NAME').append(post);
        })
    });
});`

Comment: ok cheers for that mate. Ill have a play around

Comment: It must be something deeper as opera is having none of it.